# JSON Multiple keys to one value

Tags: json, dictionary

I wish to be able to access the same data from multiple keys in a JSON file.

```
 "TypeA","TypeB","TypeC": "These types are not supported",
 "TypeR": "Vroom vroom!"
```

The actual problem is more complex, the data is a serialized object. But this is the current crux of the issue.

Comment: No, you cannot. This is a limitation of JSON specification https://www.json.org/ You have to copy you values to each key from the array ["TypeA","TypeB","TypeC"] and store it separately.

Comment: I feared this might be the case :(
Thank you @Mark.

Answer (score 2):

You could have something like:

```
{
   "TypeA" : "COMMON_TYPE_VALUE",
   "TypeB" : "COMMON_TYPE_VALUE",
   "TypeC" : "COMMON_TYPE_VALUE",
   "COMMON_TYPE_VALUE" : "here is the common value"
}
```

You'd have to know all the common keys up front of course...

Comment: This is my current plan. Have to discuss with the team :/

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you might need to make it relational.

```
"Types": [
  "These types are not supported",
  "Vroom vroom!"
],
...
"TypeA": 0,
"TypeB": 0,
"TypeC": 0,
"TypeR": 1
```

Maybe not the best structure but it highlights the idea.